# Masking area where I can draw text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

My game has online highscore, and I present this in a page that contains a top row containing a back button and a title. The rest of the page is used for the top 10 scores.

Problem is that in landscape mode the screen only contains 9 of the 10 elements. So I implemented dragging so the user kan drag the list up and down to see the whole list.

But by dragging the list upwards it's items gets under the back button and the title. Can I somehow mask away the list for every item above `y=80`?

The back button and title is a png with transparent background so it does not look good at all :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by sccisor rectangle clipping or changing your camera viewport...

a. You can change the viewport

```
 GraphicsDevice.Viewport = yourCamera.Viewport;   
 GraphicsDevice.Viewport = new Viewport(yourClippingArea);
```

b. You can use an scissor rectangle... setting a rasterizer state with scissor test enabled...

```
 GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = yourClippingArea;    
 GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = new RasterizerState( ) { ScissorTestEnabled = true };
```